# Which Javascript interpreter or parser shall I use to build a coding challenge on the web?

Tags: javascript, parsing, compilation

I am trying to build a coding game on the web, similar to code.org (see below screen shot) where the user writes code (in Javascript or other language) in a code editor to move a character on the canvas.

For this, I plan to take the code (the user entered) from the editor and pass it to an interpreter/parser, I would like the interpreter/parser to be able to Parse/Interpret the code (see below code). I am looking at [JS interpreter](https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/), from my understanding it doesn't look like it being comprehensive enough to fit my needs.

I am new to interpreters and parsers, I need help to figure out which parser I shall be using ?
Any advice or pointers to achieve my goal would be great.

```
if isOnGem {
  collectGem();
  moveForward();
}
```

Coding game from Code.org (with CodeEditor & Canvas).

[image]

Comment: Looking at your image, have your considered a block-based code editor like https://developers.google.com/blockly to integrate instead of an interpreter?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but my users would enter the code in the editor (it is designed for advanced users).